# How to have pip uninstall remove files created after installation?

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I'm creating a pip package that ships with gzipped files and unzips them the first time the module is imported. I realize this is unusual and not really a great idea, but given my constraints it seems to be the best way to ship the data.

One problem I noticed is that if you uninstall the package via pip, the extracted files are not deleted and pip gives this message:

```
Would not remove (might be manually added):
  file1
  file2
```

Is there somewhere in `setup.py` that I can specify that these files belong to my package and should be removed when it's uninstalled?

Comment: What are your constraints? Can't those extra files be distributed as standard _package data_ (uncompressed) instead?

Answer (score 4):

If you create empty files with the same name as the files you're going to create and add them to your package, then pip will recognize them as part of your package and remove them when uninstalling your package. So there's no mechanism in `setup.py` or whatever for specifying paths, but using dummy files works.